# Spring boot CommandLineRunner exception handling recommendation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have spring boot command line application and I would like to handle application errors in the way that will allow me to propagate them to user through exit codes, plus some sensible error message in error log(not just meaningless stacktrace). I found in the documentation that application exceptions should implement ExitCodeGenerator, so I followed this recommendation. But should I catch this exception in the public void run(String... args) method or spring boot will handle this for me? Also is there some best practice when it comes to spring boot commandlinerunner and exception handling? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pretty way (one that I know for what it matters) like an ExceptionHandler for example. You could use `System.exit(exitCode)` and Spring will cleanly shutdown without any stackatraces printed.

```
try {
  ....
} catch (MyException e) {
  System.err.println("Error message");
  System.exit(1);
}
```